# Python requests download zip file on request.post

Tags: python, django

I have two servers:
First server send some files to second server and then get the zip file. I need get this zip file from response.
My first server:

```
files = {'file': ...}
ceb_response = requests.post(ceb, files=files)
```

My second server respond:

```
return HttpResponse(open('db.zip', 'rb'))
```

I need to save db.zip file in first server, how can I get the file from <Response [200]> and save file locally on first server?

Answer (score 1):

The response from your second server carry your zip file by byte[].

You can save the file in the 1st server like:

```
fileName = '/xxx/db.zip' 
with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ceb_response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

```
 import io, requests, pyzipper

    r = requests.post(ceb + 'sync', files=files)

    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)) as zf:
        zf.setpassword(b'1111')
        print(zf)
```